# Decision trees calculation of the influence of the variable on the final result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, jupyter, decision-tree

I have 4 age groups as in the code below:

```
Covid.loc[Covid['AGE']<=19, 'age_group'] = '1'
Covid.loc[Covid['AGE'].between(20,40), 'age_group'] = '2'
Covid.loc[Covid['AGE'].between(41,60), 'age_group'] = '3'
Covid.loc[Covid['AGE']>60, 'age_group'] = '4'
```

[image: Table]

How can I calculate which age group has the greatest impact on the risk of death?

Here is all code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import pandas as pd

Covid = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Medion/Desktop/Projekt Prognozowanie/Covid19.csv")
Covid = Covid.sample(300)

Covid.loc[Covid['AGE']<=19, 'age_group'] = '1'
Covid.loc[Covid['AGE'].between(20,40), 'age_group'] = '2'
Covid.loc[Covid['AGE'].between(41,60), 'age_group'] = '3'
Covid.loc[Covid['AGE']>60, 'age_group'] = '4'
Covid = Covid.drop('AGE', axis=1)

Covid.drop(Covid[Covid['OBESITY'] == 98].index, inplace = True)
Covid.drop(Covid[Covid['DIABETES'] == 98].index, inplace = True)
Covid.drop(Covid[Covid['TOBACCO'] == 98].index, inplace = True)

Covid["DATE_DIED"].replace("9999-99-99", 2, inplace=True)
mask = Covid["DATE_DIED"] != 2
Covid.loc[mask, "DATE_DIED"] = 1
Covid["DATE_DIED"] = Covid["DATE_DIED"].astype('int64')
Covid = Covid.loc[:, ["SEX","DIABETES","OBESITY","TOBACCO","age_group","DATE_DIED"]]
Covid.head()

X = Covid.iloc[:,:-1]
y = Covid.iloc[:,-1]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.35)

tree_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5)
tree_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

column_names_X = X.columns.values.tolist()

from sklearn import tree
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,20))
_ = tree.plot_tree(tree_clf, 
                   feature_names=column_names_X,  
                   class_names={0:'Dead', 1:'Alive'},
                   filled=True,
                  fontsize=12)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
y_pred = tree_clf.predict(X_test)
print("\033[1m Accuracy of Decision Tree Classifier on test set:","{:.2%}".format(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)))

feature_labels = column_names_X
importance = tree_clf.feature_importances_
feature_indexes_by_importance = importance.argsort()[::-1]
for index in feature_indexes_by_importance:
 print('{}-{:.2f}%'.format(feature_labels[index], (importance[index] *100.0)))
```

Comment: You are already printing the feature importance (sorted), is that not enough?

Comment: Whats exactly wrong with your code?